# Delphi FireDAC and update with FDUpdateSQL class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac

I have used FDQuery (Delphi XE5 and SQL Server 2008) and set SQL prop to the following SQL command :

```
select LetterId, LetterTitle, LetterDate
from Letters
```

and the FDUpdateSQL assigned it to FDQuery.UpdateObject, set **FDUpdateSQL.FetchRowSQ**L to this command :

```
select LetterTitle
from Letters
where LetterID=:Old_LetterID
```

When I change the LetterTitle value and post it and then run **FDQuery.RefreshRecord**, all fields restore with null value and LetterTitle restore with posted value.

Is there a way to restore only the selected field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call **FDQuery.RefreshRecord(False)**

When the AClearRow parameter is set to True (default value), then the record is initially erased. Otherwise the read values override the corresponding column values.

[FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.RefreshRecord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.RefreshRecord)